# Applying replacement rules to products doesn't work as expected

Tags: replacement, rule

I have the following issue: I'd like to apply some replacement rules, for example

```
rules:={f[x]/t :> ff[x], g[x]/t :> gg[x]}
```

to an expression, e.g. like this:

```
(f[x]*g[x]/(t^2))/. rules
```

Surprisingly, this doesn't give the expected result

```
ff[x]*gg[x]
```

How do I fix this? Sorry if it's an easy question, I'm still a beginner with Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the forms `f[x]/t` and `g[x]/t` don't actually appear in the expression.

I try to keep the Left Hand Side of my rules as simple as possible.  In this case I'd use

```
 rules = {f[x]->t ff[x], g[x] -> t gg[x]}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try that!

Comment: maybe use a [pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) on the left-hand sides: `rules = {f[x_] -> t ff[x], g[x_] -> t gg[x]}`